# Python Pandas - Add values from one dataframe to another by matching labels to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know there is an easy, elegant solution to this problem but I am struggling to find it. All I'm trying to do is add a third column to df2 with the corresponding values from df2, based on Date and PN. There may be values in df2 that don't match to df1, and vice versa (fill NaN where there is no match).

df1:

```
       2017-11-01  2017-11-02  2017-11-03
PN                                                                              
90020       105.0       105.0       105.0
90022       100.0       100.0       100.0 
90061        -3.0        -3.0        -3.0 
90065        30.0        30.0        30.0
90099         2.0         2.0         2.0
```

df2:

```
     PN       Date
4   90020 2017-11-01
9   90020 2017-11-02
12  90061 2017-11-01
13  90065 2017-11-02
17  94008 2017-11-03
```

Desired result:

```
     PN       Date      Value
4   90020 2017-11-01    105.0
9   90020 2017-11-02    105.0
12  90061 2017-11-01    -3.0
13  90065 2017-11-02    30.0
17  94008 2017-11-03    NaN
```

Comment: I think you will want to first [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) your dataframe and then do a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to bring in that second column.

Comment: No the column values actually change, this is just a snippet of the dataframe

Comment: it looks like melt reindexes, so I lose the "PN" data that I need to merge on

Comment: @bcal, see my answer, you need to use `reset_index` before you apply `pd.melt`.

Comment: You guys rock! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use `pd.melt` combined with `pd.merge`.

Just remember to `reset_index` to promote your index to a column, and then to align column names.

```
df1 = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=df.index.name)\
        .rename(columns={'variable': 'Date'})

res = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left')

#       PN        Date  value
# 0  90020  2017-11-01  105.0
# 1  90020  2017-11-02  105.0
# 2  90061  2017-11-01   -3.0
# 3  90065  2017-11-02   30.0
# 4  94008  2017-11-03    NaN
```

To maintain `df2` index:

```
res = df2.reset_index()\
         .merge(df1, how='left')\
         .set_index('index')

#           PN        Date  value
# index                          
# 4      90020  2017-11-01  105.0
# 9      90020  2017-11-02  105.0
# 12     90061  2017-11-01   -3.0
# 13     90065  2017-11-02   30.0
# 17     94008  2017-11-03    NaN
```

Comment: Nice!, but the index is not the same here.

Comment: True, but is that important (might be, but not sure). But added an update.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to create a map of df1 using `stack()` and then apply it to the zip of the columns.

```
m = df1.stack()
df2['value'] = pd.Series(list(zip(df2.PN, df2.Date))).map(m).values

#          PN        Date  value
#index                          
#4      90020  2017-11-01  105.0
#9      90020  2017-11-02  105.0
#12     90061  2017-11-01   -3.0
#13     90065  2017-11-02   30.0
#17     94008  2017-11-03    NaN
```

---

**Time comparison**:

> jpp's melt and merge:           100 loops, best of 3: 4.41 ms per loop
>
> avbr's stack and map:           100 loops, best of 3: 2.97 ms per loop
>
> ScottB's stack, reindex:        100 loops, best of 3: 3.68 ms per loop
>
> ThisGuy's function,listcomprehension: 100 loops, best of 3: 5.79 ms per loop

---

**Full example:**

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = '''\
PN         2017-11-01  2017-11-02  2017-11-03
90020       105.0       105.0       105.0
90022       100.0       100.0       100.0
90061        -3.0        -3.0        -3.0 
90065        30.0        30.0        30.0
90099         2.0         2.0         2.0'''

data2 = '''\
index     PN       Date
4   90020 2017-11-01
9   90020 2017-11-02
12  90061 2017-11-01
13  90065 2017-11-02
17  94008 2017-11-03
'''

df1 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data1), sep='\s+').set_index('PN')
df2 = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data2), sep='\s+').set_index('index')

m = df1.stack()
df2['value'] = pd.Series(list(zip(df2.PN, df2.Date))).map(m).values
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way also.

```
(df1.stack()
   .rename_axis(['PN','Date'])
   .reindex([df2.PN,df2['Date']])
   .reset_index(name='Value')
   .set_axis(df2.index, axis=0, inplace=False))
```

@AntonVBR suggest using:

```
(df1.stack()
   .rename_axis(['PN','Date'])
   .reindex([df2.PN,df2['Date']])
   .reset_index(name='Value')
   .set_index(df2.index))
```

Output:

```
       PN        Date  Value
4   90020  2017-11-01  105.0
9   90020  2017-11-02  105.0
12  90061  2017-11-01   -3.0
13  90065  2017-11-02   30.0
17  94008  2017-11-03    NaN
```

Comment: Nvm... I was on my home pc which had 0.20

Comment: Got it working now. Didn't know you could use set_axis for this, but what is the point of not using `set_index()`, which for me would be more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go. This solution is not listed above (probably because it is hardly readable and involves looping in python which can degrade performance):

```
def cnvt (i):
    try:
        return i[0]
    except(IndexError):
        return float('nan')

df3 = df2.assign(Value=list(map(cnvt,[
           df1[i][df1["PN"]==j].values 
           for i in list(df1.columns.values[1:]) 
           for j in df2["PN"]][0:len(df2["PN"]-1)]
                 )))
```

which creates `df3`:

```
          Date     PN  Value
4   2017-11-01  90020  105.0
9   2017-11-02  90020  105.0
12  2017-11-01  90061   -3.0
13  2017-11-02  90065   30.0
17  2017-11-03  94008    NaN
```

Comment: I added a time comparison. You deserve an upvote for effort but this is far from readable.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about `lookup`, but it it fail since

> KeyError: 'One or more row labels was not found'

```
#df1.lookup(df2.PN,df2.Date,na_action='ignore')

result = []
for x,y in zip(df2.PN, df2.Date):
    try:
        result.append(df1.get_value(x, y))
    except:
        result.append(np.nan)



df2['V']=result
```